# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I using only hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, antlr

I an using hibernate 5.1.0 Final version. There is no Spring, Struts, Application Server ...

When I run my method from the same package I do not get this error. But when I call this method from other package I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateNamedParameter(HqlSqlWalker.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.parameter(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3422)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1370)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4713)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2130)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:813)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:607)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

[image]

Comment: It Looks like incompatible jars. check if there is an second Version of antlr in your classpath

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I also found that its due to old version of antlr.jar.

But in addition to this I think hibernate 5.0 depends on the new version of antlr.jar (2.7.7) and this is as expected. So the conflict was not with hibernate dependencies, but in my case it was coming from velocity-tools.jar. velocity-tools -> struts-core -> antlr.jar (old version)

Comment: This is the exact situation I had with velocity tools. I had to add an exclusion to velocity-tools in my pom for antlr:antlr

Answer (score 1):

This `getLine()` method was introduced from `antlr` version 2.7.3. If you get a `NoSuchMethodError` the class loader has loaded the `AST` class from a lower/different version of `antlr`.

If you can debug the run-time, add a break point to anywhere and try to execute the following code line

```
Class.forName("antlr.collections.AST").getResource("AST.class")
```

This will show you the location that class has been loaded from.